# Poisson ratio in plastic deformation area

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain, metals

Can the Poisson ratio of metals in the plastic deformation range be assumed to be constant? If not, are there any alternative modeling approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Poisson ratio for any material undergoing large plastic deformation is typically assumed to be 1/2. This can be justified by several different arguments.

One argument uses the relation $\nu=\frac{3K-2G}{2(3K+G)}$, where $K$ is the bulk modulus and $G$ the shear modulus, which is zero for a material actively undergoing shear flow; such a material can’t sustain any additional shear load. (A similar argument can be made for Young’s modulus if the material is being actively elongated.)

Another argument is that large permanent deformation involves substantial shifting of material, far too much to be accommodated by atomic stretching of a solid material. Thus, conservation of volume can be applied, which also yields a Poisson ratio of 1/2. Does this all make sense?

Comment: Thank you for this elegant statement!
I still have two questions:
1) The given formula generally describes a linear-elastic behaviour. Can this description be used in the plastic deformation area?
2) Why can G be assumed to be zero with a given shear flow?

Comment: You’re welcome! We can imagine coming along and attempting to obtain linear elastic deformation as plastic deformation is occurring. But *any* incremental shear stress we apply gives us more shear, as the material is already shearing. A material that shears at the slightest touch has an effective shear modulus of zero. Hope this clarifies.